# AS3 Center a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a stage that is 1920 in width, the space I am trying to center my MovieClip on is 1520. My MovieClip changes based of user selections, so it could be 1023.9 or 396.8 I am trying to center this movie clip in my 1520 place. How would I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
floorplanMCAG.x = 1520 - floorplanMCAG.width;
```

But my 1023.9 MovieClip is too much to the left and my 396.8 MovieClip is a little to the right

Here is how my MovieClip is created:

```
loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadFloorplanAG);
loader.load(new URLRequest("images/" + modelAG.floorplan));

var floorplanMCAG:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

function loadFloorplanAG(e:Event):void
{
    floorplanMCAG.addChild(loader);

    floorplanMCAG.height = 468;

    floorplanMCAG.y = 570;

    floorplanMCAG.scaleX = floorplanMCAG.scaleY;

    floorplanMCAG.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;

    trace(floorplanMCAG.width);

    map_boundsFLRPLSAG = new Rectangle(520,570,floorplanMCAG.width,floorplanMCAG.height) // this defines the area in which the map should fit

    min_zoomFLRPLSAG = floorplanMCAG.scaleX;    

    //Zoom and Drag Event Listeners

    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchBeginFLRPLSAG)
    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, touchMovedFLRPLSAG)
    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchEndFLRPLSAG)

    modelInformationAG.addChild(floorplanMCAG);

    modelInformationAG.setChildIndex(floorplanMCAG, 0);
}
```

Here is modelInformationAG

```
var modelInformationAG:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
modelInformationAG.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the formula for centering your movieclip depends on where the moviclip has its registration point set. theoratically the registration point could be anywhere, but here for the 2 most common situations:

if it's set in top left corner of the mc:

```
floorplanMCAG.x = (stage.stageWidth - floorplanMCAG.width) / 2;
```

if the registration point is in the center:

```
floorplanMCAG.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
```

EDIT:

ok, I guess this should center your movieClip:

```
floorplanMCAG.x = (modelInformationAG.width - floorplanMCAG.width) / 2;
```

Comment: How do I figure out the registration point? I add my MovieClip programmatically.

Comment: if you work in flash, and you convert something into a symbol, you can set the registration point right there in the dialoge where you can name the symbol. if you are not sure what you have selected:open up the movieclip and look where the x and y coordinates are 0.

Comment: I updated my question with how I created the MovieClip

Comment: in this case the registration point of floorplanMCAG is in the top left corner but since you add it into another container everything depends on where this container is positioned and where this container has its registration point :D

Comment: var modelInformationAG:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
modelInformationAG.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);

Comment: Its still a bit off...it appears though I am on the right track, everything needs to be moved over to the right

Comment: Fixed it by adding this on the next line: `floorplanMCAG.x = floorplanMCAG.x + 200;`